# Flutter formater on VSCode Mac

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, formatting

I just tried flutter in VSCode
I'm confused when the file is saved, why is the closing tag always one line

this is after I save the file:
[image]

my expectation:
[image]

VSCode Settings:
[image]

is there any extension or some settings to make as like my expectation?
thanks

Comment: try adding a comma after closing brackets and then save.

Comment: There's even a lint you can enable to remind you to put those commas in, or even better, if you have autofix, add the commas for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings are right. This will make Dart really format your code when you save a file.

But if you want to this format break the lines, Dart expects to se a comma after the closing brackets. Example:

```
...
backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],),),);
```

Doing this, when you save, it will be formatted the way you want to.